# What do you use delays for?

Tags: delay, design, tips, techniques

What do you use delays for? Thickening? making wierd effects?  I never use them even to thicken, maybe that's because my delay is too long.  Whats up world!?

depth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes I'll use a delay in place of a reverb for things like slap echoes off of walls or buildings. Easy to achieve and doesn't muddy up the track.

Answer (score 2):

Just like birdhousesound I use multitap delays all the time for adding depth to ambiences.  But additionally in every Dolby E session I mix I have to use delay as just that, a signal delay to align the PCM stereo Mix with the Dolby E stream.

Comment: Aha! Nice. I know someone who has an HDTV with a 2-frame delay on it so he sends his whole mix through a delay for it to sync up. Hah! Talk about jerry-rigged.

Answer (score 0):

In sound design, I use delay to thicken, and occasionally for the obvious delay.  In music, I'm a delay junky, and use it for EVERYTHING from dub effects to long, evolving, soundscapes.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the others, I use it on every SFX and Atmos to give a different feel or extension. I'm a big fan of H DLY as it has a great sounding filter section.